# Protractor: TypeError: browser.driver.isElementPresent is not a function

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have updated my protractor version to 5.1.1 and node.js to 6.10.2 and now all my tests from the project fail with following error: 
TypeError: browser.driver.isElementPresent is not a function

As you can see, changing all 'browser.driver.isElementPresent' is not a solution for me as the project is large and I have there lots of lines that use this.

Do you have any ideas why this error occurs and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Is it Angular application or not?

Answer (score 6):

## browser.driver.isElementPresent has been removed.

`browser.driver` is an instance of `webdriver`. The instance created comes from the `selenium-webdriver` node module. Protractor 5.1.1 uses `selenium-webdriver` v3.0.1 and as of [v3.0.0-beta-1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md#v300-beta-2), the method `isElementPresent` was removed. In the changelog, Protractor documented a workaround.

## Before:

```
let isPresent = browser.driver.isElementPresent(By.tagName('a'));
```

## After:

```
let isPresent = element(By.tagName('a')).isPresent();
```

Comment: @craig Protractor API needs to be updated, lot of users are unaware of the changes as they look at the API docs rather than the changelog!